# How to select List<B> from List<A> where A and B are many-to-many related using Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, list, many-to-many

I have 2 models, say `Product` and `Category`:

```
public class Category
{
    public Category() { }

    // primary key
    public long Id { get; set; }

    // other properties are omitted 

    public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
}


public class Product
{
    public Product() { }

    // primary key        
    public long Id { get; set; }

    // title/name
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see there is a many-to-many relationship between these models; each product can have multiple categories and for each category we can have multiple products.

The question is how can I select distinct categories associated with a list of products. I want something like this:

```
// making a list of products
var p = db.Products.Where(i => i.Title.Contains("Apple"));

// getting distinct categories of those products
var c = p.Select(i => i.Categories)... // stuck here
```

I just want to select categories of the products that their title contains a keyword. Am I doing it right at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like:

```
var p = db.Products.
    Where(i => i.Title.Contains("Apple")).
    SelectMany(i => i.Categories).
    Distinct();
```

should do.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather start from `Categories` and apply `Any` based condition on their associated `Products`. This way the query will not need to apply `Distinct` on the result which might be costly:

```
var categories = db.Categories
    .Where(c => c.Products.Any(p => p.Title.Contains("Apple")));
```

Comment: What if we use a previously-defined List<Product>? Is this way still preferable? And there is three p inside Any!

Comment: it was my first idea, but it involves a subquery (`where exists (select ...)`). I believe that `join` are better for perf, no ?

Comment: @Mowji If you already have `List<Product>`, neither is preferable :) Except if the `Categories` collections of `Product` entities in the list are eagerly loaded, in which case the `SelectMany` + `Distinct` is better.

Comment: @tschmit007 For nowadays SQL query optimizers (CBO) it really doesn't matter if you use  `JOIN`, `IN` or `EXISTS` - they can turn one into another and produce exactly the same plan. What you are talking about is the old RBO (rule base optimizers) :)