# How to get all elements from linq query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I am currently testing my database relations using Entity Framework. I'm having trouble returning every elements from a linq query. The idea is that I have a table `Web_Profiles` that has a many-to-many relation with `Web_Categories` and knowing that I have an `ID` from both tables, using the `Profiles` I have, I can find a Category. Since there is an `ICollection` of `Web_Categories` in `Web_Profiles` I can find it using:

```
var idCategory = context.WebProfiles
                .Where(c => c.IDProfile == item)
                .Select(c => c.Categories)
                .ToList();
```

WebProfiles being a `DbSet` from my context and `Categories` is an `ICollection` as described above. The return type of this query is : `List<ICollection<Web_Categories>>`. Now when I loop through this list, if I want to retrieve the Categories associated to profiles, I only managed to retrieve one category for one profile, whereas there are many categories for many profiles. How can I do this?

This is what I have tried, making a `Select` of IDCategory property, but I don't know which method to use after the `Select` statement, to show every `Category`:

```
foreach (var id in idCategory)
{
    Console.WriteLine(id.Select(c => c.IDCategorie));
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Replace `.Select(c => c.Categories)` with `.SelectMany(c => c.Categories)`, and eventually apply `Distinct()` after.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks, this works perfectly! Where should I apply `Distinct` though? I have tried creating another IEnumerable to which I `Concat()` every IEnumerable created through the foreach, but I can't seem to apply Distinct() correctly

Comment: Right after `SelectMany`, e.g. `.SelectMany(c => c.Categories).Distinct().ToList()`

Comment: Yes but since I loop through, I still get duplicates.

Comment: But your `idCategory` now should contain a list of unique `Web_Categories`. The distinct should have been applied at SQL query level. You can take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44782360/how-to-select-listb-from-lista-where-a-and-b-are-many-to-many-related-using) which shows the two possible ways of handling this - with or without `Distinct`.

Comment: Yep, it works now, thanks man :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `id.ToList().ForEach(c => Console.WriteLine(c.IDCategorie))`

Comment: I have a problem with this, Foreach is not defined for List<Web_Categories>

Comment: @LéonardLaiter it's `ForEach`, sorry for typo